# 5974 Word Runtime Error After trying to use a macro consecutively

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have 2 macros stored in Word template. We use the template for writing consistency and the format of a bulleted list and a multilevel list matter. So instead of manually setting a multilevel list each time we have a macro that inserts a short list with text placeholders. When I use each macro 1 time there is no issue. However, if I use the multilevel list after I have used the bulleted list I get a runtime 5974 runtime error that says "Bullet format strings cannot have number placeholders". The debug highlights the line with the .NumberFormat = "%1%.

I am NOT running the multilevel macro immediately after but maybe a couple pages in the document. The error doesn't make sense because of course you can have bullets in a number list.

I also admit that I used the macro recorder which I am sure is the culprit.

To be clear, if I only use multilevel list then there no problems. It is only if I have used the bullet macro do I get the error. Both macros are below.

```
Sub MultilevelList()
    With ListGalleries(wdOutlineNumberGallery).ListTemplates(1).ListLevels(1)
        .NumberFormat = "%1."
        .TrailingCharacter = wdTrailingTab
        .NumberStyle = wdListNumberStyleArabic
        .NumberPosition = InchesToPoints(0)
        .Alignment = wdListLevelAlignLeft
        .TextPosition = InchesToPoints(0.25)
        .TabPosition = wdUndefined
        .ResetOnHigher = 0
        .StartAt = 1
        With .Font
            .Bold = wdUndefined
            .Italic = wdUndefined
            .StrikeThrough = wdUndefined
            .Subscript = wdUndefined
            .Superscript = wdUndefined
            .Shadow = wdUndefined
            .Outline = wdUndefined
            .Emboss = wdUndefined
            .Engrave = wdUndefined
            .AllCaps = wdUndefined
            .Hidden = wdUndefined
            .Underline = wdUndefined
            .Color = wdUndefined
            .Size = wdUndefined
            .Animation = wdUndefined
            .DoubleStrikeThrough = wdUndefined
            .Name = ""
        End With
        .LinkedStyle = ""
    End With
    With ListGalleries(wdOutlineNumberGallery).ListTemplates(1).ListLevels(2)
        .NumberFormat = "o"
        .TrailingCharacter = wdTrailingTab
        .NumberStyle = wdListNumberStyleLowercaseLetter
        .NumberPosition = InchesToPoints(0.25)
        .Alignment = wdListLevelAlignLeft
        .TextPosition = InchesToPoints(0.5)
        .TabPosition = wdUndefined
        .ResetOnHigher = 1
        .StartAt = 1
        With .Font
            .Bold = wdUndefined
            .Italic = wdUndefined
            .StrikeThrough = wdUndefined
            .Subscript = wdUndefined
            .Superscript = wdUndefined
            .Shadow = wdUndefined
            .Outline = wdUndefined
            .Emboss = wdUndefined
            .Engrave = wdUndefined
            .AllCaps = wdUndefined
            .Hidden = wdUndefined
            .Underline = wdUndefined
            .Color = wdUndefined
            .Size = wdUndefined
            .Animation = wdUndefined
            .DoubleStrikeThrough = wdUndefined
            .Name = "Courier New"
        End With
        .LinkedStyle = ""
    End With
    With ListGalleries(wdOutlineNumberGallery).ListTemplates(1).ListLevels(3)
        .NumberFormat = Chrw(61607)
        .TrailingCharacter = wdTrailingTab
        .NumberStyle = wdListNumberStyleLowercaseRoman
        .NumberPosition = InchesToPoints(0.5)
        .Alignment = wdListLevelAlignLeft
        .TextPosition = InchesToPoints(0.75)
        .TabPosition = wdUndefined
        .ResetOnHigher = 2
        .StartAt = 1
        With .Font
            .Bold = wdUndefined
            .Italic = wdUndefined
            .StrikeThrough = wdUndefined
            .Subscript = wdUndefined
            .Superscript = wdUndefined
            .Shadow = wdUndefined
            .Outline = wdUndefined
            .Emboss = wdUndefined
            .Engrave = wdUndefined
            .AllCaps = wdUndefined
            .Hidden = wdUndefined
            .Underline = wdUndefined
            .Color = wdUndefined
            .Size = wdUndefined
            .Animation = wdUndefined
            .DoubleStrikeThrough = wdUndefined
            .Name = "Wingdings"
        End With
        .LinkedStyle = ""
    End With
    With ListGalleries(wdOutlineNumberGallery).ListTemplates(1).ListLevels(4)
        .NumberFormat = Chrw(61607)
        .TrailingCharacter = wdTrailingTab
        .NumberStyle = wdListNumberStyleArabic
        .NumberPosition = InchesToPoints(0.75)
        .Alignment = wdListLevelAlignLeft
        .TextPosition = InchesToPoints(1)
        .TabPosition = wdUndefined
        .ResetOnHigher = 3
        .StartAt = 1
        With .Font
            .Bold = wdUndefined
            .Italic = wdUndefined
            .StrikeThrough = wdUndefined
            .Subscript = wdUndefined
            .Superscript = wdUndefined
            .Shadow = wdUndefined
            .Outline = wdUndefined
            .Emboss = wdUndefined
            .Engrave = wdUndefined
            .AllCaps = wdUndefined
            .Hidden = wdUndefined
            .Underline = wdUndefined
            .Color = wdUndefined
            .Size = wdUndefined
            .Animation = wdUndefined
            .DoubleStrikeThrough = wdUndefined
            .Name = "Wingdings"
        End With
        .LinkedStyle = ""
    End With
    With ListGalleries(wdOutlineNumberGallery).ListTemplates(1).ListLevels(5)
        .NumberFormat = Chrw(61607)
        .TrailingCharacter = wdTrailingTab
        .NumberStyle = wdListNumberStyleLowercaseLetter
        .NumberPosition = InchesToPoints(1)
        .Alignment = wdListLevelAlignLeft
        .TextPosition = InchesToPoints(1.25)
        .TabPosition = wdUndefined
        .ResetOnHigher = 4
        .StartAt = 1
        With .Font
            .Bold = wdUndefined
            .Italic = wdUndefined
            .StrikeThrough = wdUndefined
            .Subscript = wdUndefined
            .Superscript = wdUndefined
            .Shadow = wdUndefined
            .Outline = wdUndefined
            .Emboss = wdUndefined
            .Engrave = wdUndefined
            .AllCaps = wdUndefined
            .Hidden = wdUndefined
            .Underline = wdUndefined
            .Color = wdUndefined
            .Size = wdUndefined
            .Animation = wdUndefined
            .DoubleStrikeThrough = wdUndefined
            .Name = "Wingdings"
        End With
        .LinkedStyle = ""
    End With
    With ListGalleries(wdOutlineNumberGallery).ListTemplates(1).ListLevels(6)
        .NumberFormat = Chrw(61607)
        .TrailingCharacter = wdTrailingTab
        .NumberStyle = wdListNumberStyleLowercaseRoman
        .NumberPosition = InchesToPoints(1.25)
        .Alignment = wdListLevelAlignLeft
        .TextPosition = InchesToPoints(1.5)
        .TabPosition = wdUndefined
        .ResetOnHigher = 5
        .StartAt = 1
        With .Font
            .Bold = wdUndefined
            .Italic = wdUndefined
            .StrikeThrough = wdUndefined
            .Subscript = wdUndefined
            .Superscript = wdUndefined
            .Shadow = wdUndefined
            .Outline = wdUndefined
            .Emboss = wdUndefined
            .Engrave = wdUndefined
            .AllCaps = wdUndefined
            .Hidden = wdUndefined
            .Underline = wdUndefined
            .Color = wdUndefined
            .Size = wdUndefined
            .Animation = wdUndefined
            .DoubleStrikeThrough = wdUndefined
            .Name = "Wingdings"
        End With
        .LinkedStyle = ""
    End With
    With ListGalleries(wdOutlineNumberGallery).ListTemplates(1).ListLevels(7)
        .NumberFormat = Chrw(61607)
        .TrailingCharacter = wdTrailingTab
        .NumberStyle = wdListNumberStyleArabic
        .NumberPosition = InchesToPoints(1.5)
        .Alignment = wdListLevelAlignLeft
        .TextPosition = InchesToPoints(1.75)
        .TabPosition = wdUndefined
        .ResetOnHigher = 6
        .StartAt = 1
        With .Font
            .Bold = wdUndefined
            .Italic = wdUndefined
            .StrikeThrough = wdUndefined
            .Subscript = wdUndefined
            .Superscript = wdUndefined
            .Shadow = wdUndefined
            .Outline = wdUndefined
            .Emboss = wdUndefined
            .Engrave = wdUndefined
            .AllCaps = wdUndefined
            .Hidden = wdUndefined
            .Underline = wdUndefined
            .Color = wdUndefined
            .Size = wdUndefined
            .Animation = wdUndefined
            .DoubleStrikeThrough = wdUndefined
            .Name = "Wingdings"
        End With
        .LinkedStyle = ""
    End With
    With ListGalleries(wdOutlineNumberGallery).ListTemplates(1).ListLevels(8)
        .NumberFormat = Chrw(61607)
        .TrailingCharacter = wdTrailingTab
        .NumberStyle = wdListNumberStyleLowercaseLetter
        .NumberPosition = InchesToPoints(1.75)
        .Alignment = wdListLevelAlignLeft
        .TextPosition = InchesToPoints(2)
        .TabPosition = wdUndefined
        .ResetOnHigher = 7
        .StartAt = 1
        With .Font
            .Bold = wdUndefined
            .Italic = wdUndefined
            .StrikeThrough = wdUndefined
            .Subscript = wdUndefined
            .Superscript = wdUndefined
            .Shadow = wdUndefined
            .Outline = wdUndefined
            .Emboss = wdUndefined
            .Engrave = wdUndefined
            .AllCaps = wdUndefined
            .Hidden = wdUndefined
            .Underline = wdUndefined
            .Color = wdUndefined
            .Size = wdUndefined
            .Animation = wdUndefined
            .DoubleStrikeThrough = wdUndefined
            .Name = "Wingdings"
        End With
        .LinkedStyle = ""
    End With
    With ListGalleries(wdOutlineNumberGallery).ListTemplates(1).ListLevels(9)
        .NumberFormat = Chrw(61607)
        .TrailingCharacter = wdTrailingTab
        .NumberStyle = wdListNumberStyleLowercaseRoman
        .NumberPosition = InchesToPoints(2)
        .Alignment = wdListLevelAlignLeft
        .TextPosition = InchesToPoints(2.25)
        .TabPosition = wdUndefined
        .ResetOnHigher = 8
        .StartAt = 1
        With .Font
            .Bold = wdUndefined
            .Italic = wdUndefined
            .StrikeThrough = wdUndefined
            .Subscript = wdUndefined
            .Superscript = wdUndefined
            .Shadow = wdUndefined
            .Outline = wdUndefined
            .Emboss = wdUndefined
            .Engrave = wdUndefined
            .AllCaps = wdUndefined
            .Hidden = wdUndefined
            .Underline = wdUndefined
            .Color = wdUndefined
            .Size = wdUndefined
            .Animation = wdUndefined
            .DoubleStrikeThrough = wdUndefined
            .Name = "Wingdings"
        End With
        .LinkedStyle = ""
    End With
    ListGalleries(wdOutlineNumberGallery).ListTemplates(1).Name = ""
    Selection.Range.ListFormat.ApplyListTemplateWithLevel ListTemplate:= _
        ListGalleries(wdOutlineNumberGallery).ListTemplates(1), _
        ContinuePreviousList:=False, ApplyTo:=wdListApplyToWholeList, _
        DefaultListBehavior:=wdWord10ListBehavior
    Selection.TypeText Text:="Test"
    Selection.TypeParagraph
    Selection.TypeText Text:="Test"
End Sub

    Sub NumberList()
    With ListGalleries(wdOutlineNumberGallery).ListTemplates(1).ListLevels(1)
        .NumberFormat = "%1."
        .TrailingCharacter = wdTrailingTab
        .NumberStyle = wdListNumberStyleArabic
        .NumberPosition = InchesToPoints(0)
        .Alignment = wdListLevelAlignLeft
        .TextPosition = InchesToPoints(0.25)
        .TabPosition = wdUndefined
        .ResetOnHigher = 0
        .StartAt = 1
        With .Font
            .Bold = wdUndefined
            .Italic = wdUndefined
            .StrikeThrough = wdUndefined
            .Subscript = wdUndefined
            .Superscript = wdUndefined
            .Shadow = wdUndefined
            .Outline = wdUndefined
            .Emboss = wdUndefined
            .Engrave = wdUndefined
            .AllCaps = wdUndefined
            .Hidden = wdUndefined
            .Underline = wdUndefined
            .Color = wdUndefined
            .Size = wdUndefined
            .Animation = wdUndefined
            .DoubleStrikeThrough = wdUndefined
            .Name = ""
        End With
        .LinkedStyle = ""
    End With
    With ListGalleries(wdOutlineNumberGallery).ListTemplates(1).ListLevels(2)
        .NumberFormat = "o"
        .TrailingCharacter = wdTrailingTab
        .NumberStyle = wdListNumberStyleLowercaseLetter
        .NumberPosition = InchesToPoints(0.25)
        .Alignment = wdListLevelAlignLeft
        .TextPosition = InchesToPoints(0.5)
        .TabPosition = wdUndefined
        .ResetOnHigher = 1
        .StartAt = 1
        With .Font
            .Bold = wdUndefined
            .Italic = wdUndefined
            .StrikeThrough = wdUndefined
            .Subscript = wdUndefined
            .Superscript = wdUndefined
            .Shadow = wdUndefined
            .Outline = wdUndefined
            .Emboss = wdUndefined
            .Engrave = wdUndefined
            .AllCaps = wdUndefined
            .Hidden = wdUndefined
            .Underline = wdUndefined
            .Color = wdUndefined
            .Size = wdUndefined
            .Animation = wdUndefined
            .DoubleStrikeThrough = wdUndefined
            .Name = "Courier New"
        End With
        .LinkedStyle = ""
    End With
    With ListGalleries(wdOutlineNumberGallery).ListTemplates(1).ListLevels(3)
        .NumberFormat = Chrw(61607)
        .TrailingCharacter = wdTrailingTab
        .NumberStyle = wdListNumberStyleLowercaseRoman
        .NumberPosition = InchesToPoints(0.5)
        .Alignment = wdListLevelAlignLeft
        .TextPosition = InchesToPoints(0.75)
        .TabPosition = wdUndefined
        .ResetOnHigher = 2
        .StartAt = 1
        With .Font
            .Bold = wdUndefined
            .Italic = wdUndefined
            .StrikeThrough = wdUndefined
            .Subscript = wdUndefined
            .Superscript = wdUndefined
            .Shadow = wdUndefined
            .Outline = wdUndefined
            .Emboss = wdUndefined
            .Engrave = wdUndefined
            .AllCaps = wdUndefined
            .Hidden = wdUndefined
            .Underline = wdUndefined
            .Color = wdUndefined
            .Size = wdUndefined
            .Animation = wdUndefined
            .DoubleStrikeThrough = wdUndefined
            .Name = "Wingdings"
        End With
        .LinkedStyle = ""
    End With
    With ListGalleries(wdOutlineNumberGallery).ListTemplates(1).ListLevels(4)
        .NumberFormat = Chrw(61607)
        .TrailingCharacter = wdTrailingTab
        .NumberStyle = wdListNumberStyleArabic
        .NumberPosition = InchesToPoints(0.75)
        .Alignment = wdListLevelAlignLeft
        .TextPosition = InchesToPoints(1)
        .TabPosition = wdUndefined
        .ResetOnHigher = 3
        .StartAt = 1
        With .Font
            .Bold = wdUndefined
            .Italic = wdUndefined
            .StrikeThrough = wdUndefined
            .Subscript = wdUndefined
            .Superscript = wdUndefined
            .Shadow = wdUndefined
            .Outline = wdUndefined
            .Emboss = wdUndefined
            .Engrave = wdUndefined
            .AllCaps = wdUndefined
            .Hidden = wdUndefined
            .Underline = wdUndefined
            .Color = wdUndefined
            .Size = wdUndefined
            .Animation = wdUndefined
            .DoubleStrikeThrough = wdUndefined
            .Name = "Wingdings"
        End With
        .LinkedStyle = ""
    End With
    With ListGalleries(wdOutlineNumberGallery).ListTemplates(1).ListLevels(5)
        .NumberFormat = Chrw(61607)
        .TrailingCharacter = wdTrailingTab
        .NumberStyle = wdListNumberStyleLowercaseLetter
        .NumberPosition = InchesToPoints(1)
        .Alignment = wdListLevelAlignLeft
        .TextPosition = InchesToPoints(1.25)
        .TabPosition = wdUndefined
        .ResetOnHigher = 4
        .StartAt = 1
        With .Font
            .Bold = wdUndefined
            .Italic = wdUndefined
            .StrikeThrough = wdUndefined
            .Subscript = wdUndefined
            .Superscript = wdUndefined
            .Shadow = wdUndefined
            .Outline = wdUndefined
            .Emboss = wdUndefined
            .Engrave = wdUndefined
            .AllCaps = wdUndefined
            .Hidden = wdUndefined
            .Underline = wdUndefined
            .Color = wdUndefined
            .Size = wdUndefined
            .Animation = wdUndefined
            .DoubleStrikeThrough = wdUndefined
            .Name = "Wingdings"
        End With
        .LinkedStyle = ""
    End With
    With ListGalleries(wdOutlineNumberGallery).ListTemplates(1).ListLevels(6)
        .NumberFormat = Chrw(61607)
        .TrailingCharacter = wdTrailingTab
        .NumberStyle = wdListNumberStyleLowercaseRoman
        .NumberPosition = InchesToPoints(1.25)
        .Alignment = wdListLevelAlignLeft
        .TextPosition = InchesToPoints(1.5)
        .TabPosition = wdUndefined
        .ResetOnHigher = 5
        .StartAt = 1
        With .Font
            .Bold = wdUndefined
            .Italic = wdUndefined
            .StrikeThrough = wdUndefined
            .Subscript = wdUndefined
            .Superscript = wdUndefined
            .Shadow = wdUndefined
            .Outline = wdUndefined
            .Emboss = wdUndefined
            .Engrave = wdUndefined
            .AllCaps = wdUndefined
            .Hidden = wdUndefined
            .Underline = wdUndefined
            .Color = wdUndefined
            .Size = wdUndefined
            .Animation = wdUndefined
            .DoubleStrikeThrough = wdUndefined
            .Name = "Wingdings"
        End With
        .LinkedStyle = ""
    End With
    With ListGalleries(wdOutlineNumberGallery).ListTemplates(1).ListLevels(7)
        .NumberFormat = Chrw(61607)
        .TrailingCharacter = wdTrailingTab
        .NumberStyle = wdListNumberStyleArabic
        .NumberPosition = InchesToPoints(1.5)
        .Alignment = wdListLevelAlignLeft
        .TextPosition = InchesToPoints(1.75)
        .TabPosition = wdUndefined
        .ResetOnHigher = 6
        .StartAt = 1
        With .Font
            .Bold = wdUndefined
            .Italic = wdUndefined
            .StrikeThrough = wdUndefined
            .Subscript = wdUndefined
            .Superscript = wdUndefined
            .Shadow = wdUndefined
            .Outline = wdUndefined
            .Emboss = wdUndefined
            .Engrave = wdUndefined
            .AllCaps = wdUndefined
            .Hidden = wdUndefined
            .Underline = wdUndefined
            .Color = wdUndefined
            .Size = wdUndefined
            .Animation = wdUndefined
            .DoubleStrikeThrough = wdUndefined
            .Name = "Wingdings"
        End With
        .LinkedStyle = ""
    End With
    With ListGalleries(wdOutlineNumberGallery).ListTemplates(1).ListLevels(8)
        .NumberFormat = Chrw(61607)
        .TrailingCharacter = wdTrailingTab
        .NumberStyle = wdListNumberStyleLowercaseLetter
        .NumberPosition = InchesToPoints(1.75)
        .Alignment = wdListLevelAlignLeft
        .TextPosition = InchesToPoints(2)
        .TabPosition = wdUndefined
        .ResetOnHigher = 7
        .StartAt = 1
        With .Font
            .Bold = wdUndefined
            .Italic = wdUndefined
            .StrikeThrough = wdUndefined
            .Subscript = wdUndefined
            .Superscript = wdUndefined
            .Shadow = wdUndefined
            .Outline = wdUndefined
            .Emboss = wdUndefined
            .Engrave = wdUndefined
            .AllCaps = wdUndefined
            .Hidden = wdUndefined
            .Underline = wdUndefined
            .Color = wdUndefined
            .Size = wdUndefined
            .Animation = wdUndefined
            .DoubleStrikeThrough = wdUndefined
            .Name = "Wingdings"
        End With
        .LinkedStyle = ""
    End With
    With ListGalleries(wdOutlineNumberGallery).ListTemplates(1).ListLevels(9)
        .NumberFormat = Chrw(61607)
        .TrailingCharacter = wdTrailingTab
        .NumberStyle = wdListNumberStyleLowercaseRoman
        .NumberPosition = InchesToPoints(2)
        .Alignment = wdListLevelAlignLeft
        .TextPosition = InchesToPoints(2.25)
        .TabPosition = wdUndefined
        .ResetOnHigher = 8
        .StartAt = 1
        With .Font
            .Bold = wdUndefined
            .Italic = wdUndefined
            .StrikeThrough = wdUndefined
            .Subscript = wdUndefined
            .Superscript = wdUndefined
            .Shadow = wdUndefined
            .Outline = wdUndefined
            .Emboss = wdUndefined
            .Engrave = wdUndefined
            .AllCaps = wdUndefined
            .Hidden = wdUndefined
            .Underline = wdUndefined
            .Color = wdUndefined
            .Size = wdUndefined
            .Animation = wdUndefined
            .DoubleStrikeThrough = wdUndefined
            .Name = "Wingdings"
        End With
        .LinkedStyle = ""
    End With
    ListGalleries(wdOutlineNumberGallery).ListTemplates(1).Name = "Multilevel"
    Selection.Range.ListFormat.ApplyListTemplateWithLevel ListTemplate:= _
        ListGalleries(wdOutlineNumberGallery).ListTemplates(1), _
        ContinuePreviousList:=False, ApplyTo:=wdListApplyToWholeList, _
        DefaultListBehavior:=wdWord10ListBehavior
    Selection.TypeText Text:="Test"
    Selection.TypeParagraph
    Selection.range.ListFormat.ListIndent
    Selection.TypeText Text:="Test"
    Selection.TypeParagraph
    Selection.range.ListFormat.ListIndent
    Selection.TypeText Text:="Test"
End Sub

Sub NumberList()
    With ListGalleries(wdOutlineNumberGallery).ListTemplates(1).ListLevels(1)
        .NumberFormat = .numberformat = Chrw(61623)
        .TrailingCharacter = wdTrailingTab
        .NumberStyle = wdListNumberStyleArabic
        .NumberPosition = InchesToPoints(0)
        .Alignment = wdListLevelAlignLeft
        .TextPosition = InchesToPoints(0.25)
        .TabPosition = wdUndefined
        .ResetOnHigher = 0
        .StartAt = 1
        With .Font
            .Bold = wdUndefined
            .Italic = wdUndefined
            .StrikeThrough = wdUndefined
            .Subscript = wdUndefined
            .Superscript = wdUndefined
            .Shadow = wdUndefined
            .Outline = wdUndefined
            .Emboss = wdUndefined
            .Engrave = wdUndefined
            .AllCaps = wdUndefined
            .Hidden = wdUndefined
            .Underline = wdUndefined
            .Color = wdUndefined
            .Size = wdUndefined
            .Animation = wdUndefined
            .DoubleStrikeThrough = wdUndefined
            .Name = "Symbol"
        End With
        .LinkedStyle = ""
    End With
    With ListGalleries(wdOutlineNumberGallery).ListTemplates(1).ListLevels(2)
        .NumberFormat = "o"
        .TrailingCharacter = wdTrailingTab
        .NumberStyle = wdListNumberStyleLowercaseLetter
        .NumberPosition = InchesToPoints(0.25)
        .Alignment = wdListLevelAlignLeft
        'the code is the same as previous macro and Stack has a character limit
End Sub
```

Comment: I believe you asked this already yesterday, and have deleted that in the meantime? And I asked you to please provide a set of steps to reproduce the problem, that you could use the [edit] link below the question to change it? Please do so, this time. You're asking professionals to take time out of their day to help you - it's to your best advantage to streamline the process for them as much as possible. A hit-and-miss approach to testing a problem such as this wastes our time and yours. On Stack Overflow you want to be careful about deleting your questions - it could lead to a question ban.

Comment: You are correct and the post was closed so I created a new one where I (thought) I provided more detail about what is happening. I have tried to explain what I do and when it works and when it doesn't. It is not hit or miss for me, I can reproduce it 100% of the time. I can't post both macros because Stack Overflow has a character limit.

Answer (score 0):

Both routines in your code refer to ListTemplates(1). Each list in Word has its own list template and a list template can only have one definition.

> We use the template for writing consistency and the format of a
>   bulleted list and a multilevel list matter.

As you are using a template there is no need to use VBA. Just set the lists up correctly as List Styles attached to paragraph styles. You will find a [full set of instructions](https://shaunakelly.com/word/numbering/numbering20072010.html) on Shauna Kelly's website. Although the article refers to headings the same instructions apply for any multi-level list and can also be used for bullets.